# Android Studio エミュレーター実行時エラー

Tags: android, java, android-activity

Android Studio version 2.2.2にてアプリの開発をしています。

メニューバー▼から、エミュレーターを起動すると
エミュレーター(Androidスマートフォン画面)が、通常通り表示されます。

しばらくして、正常であれば実行されるはずのアプリが実行されず
空白の画面で停止します。
※ソースコード上にはエラーはありません。
monitorには、以下の実行エラーコードが表示されます。

```
***E/InputChannel-JNI: Error 9 dup channel fd -2147483647.***
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                  --------- beginning of crash
***E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: jp.atue.mbap_fw, PID: 2632
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel.
    at android.view.InputChannel.nativeReadFromParcel(Native Method)
    at android.view.InputChannel.readFromParcel(InputChannel.java:148)
    at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.addToDisplay(IWindowSession.java:841)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:639)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:342)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3488)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2713)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)***
Application terminated.
```

「java.lang.RuntimeException:」の文字列で検索するとエラーの内容が
いくつか上がるのですが、ボタンを2つ表示するだけの画面なので該当しないと思われます。

Comment: ＪＮＩを使用して何かしていませんか？

Comment: 「Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel」と例外をあげた理由が書かれているのですから、InputChannel.javaの中で関係しそうな値をデバッグプリントするなどしては如何ですか？　「ボタンを2つ表示するだけの画面なので該当しないと思われます」というような感想は、実際に例外が出ている現実に向き合うのに役立つとは思えません。　デバッグには、謙虚にひとつづつ可能性をつぶしていく作業が必須です。

Comment: 本家のstackoverflowに同様の質問が上がっており、SoundPool辺りが怪しいのか？くらいまでは分かりましたが、実際のコードがわからないとなんとも言えないですね……実際にエラーが起きているActivityのソースコードを添付することは出来ませんか？
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582648/could-not-read-input-channel-file-descriptors-from-parcel